# Sticky sidebar not working on short articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing is, sticky widget works well on longer articles but is not working on short articles on my site.
Here is long article: 
http://www.hddmag.com/2015/06/best-hard-drive.html and the sticky is working fine, no lags.

Now shorter article. In shorter articles I can't scroll to the bottom, the sticky is lagging and not allowing to do that.
http://www.hddmag.com/2016/06/western-digital-introduced-new-external.html

Heres the code for sticky:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
   if ($(&#39;#HTML4&#39;).length) { // make sure &quot;#sticky&quot; element exists
      var el = $(&#39;#HTML4&#39;);
      var stickyTop = $(&#39;#HTML4&#39;).offset().top; // returns number
      var stickyHeight = $(&#39;#HTML4&#39;).height();

      $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
          var limit = $(&#39;#copyrights&#39;).offset().top - stickyHeight - 600;

          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          if (windowTop &gt; stickyTop) {
             el.css({ position: &#39;fixed&#39;, top: 25 });
          }
          else {
             el.css(&#39;position&#39;,&#39;static&#39;);
          }

          if (windowTop &gt; limit) {
          var diff = limit - windowTop;
          el.css({top: diff});
          }
        });
   }
});
```

I'm not a pro programmer; maybe the solution is very simple.

Comment: It contains encoded HTML ...like `&#39;#HTML4&#39;`

Comment: So it is not working because of encoded HTML?

Comment: Yes, where did you copy it from?

Comment: I'm surfing websites that have tips and tricks for blogger.

Comment: I'm using blogger so I can't do it without encoded HTML, as far as I understand

Comment: HTML is not the problem... There is something not right within this line ( I think so) 
else {
             el.css(&#39;position&#39;,&#39;static&#39;);
When I remove it I then can scroll to the bottom (in short posts) but the sticky will go up, over all other widgeds (when scrolling up).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I'm assuming you are talking about the amazon sticky banner. On the first URL I can see the banner clearing cookies, using a US IP address, etc. Not in the second article. Checking and comparing downloaded JS in both sites I have noticed you are not inserting the following script in the second article:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "hd02d5-20";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "manual";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "c7d729574dff35b824e7c6ea36cc5357";
amzn_assoc_asins =     "B00P0NV43E,B0143BOR5A,B00LO3KR96,B00XS423SC,B013HNYVCE,B00FJRS5BA,B00LO3KMK0,B00GSJ9X4Q,B00FQH7MQ2";
amzn_assoc_title = "Today`s Best Deals";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

With that script the banner gets loaded (now you should check if the values of the first script are the right ones since it's a copy-paste from the first article).

Here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8k0H.jpg

---

### Old wrong answer

The code has been copy-pasted incorrectly in the post but checking the source-code of your both pages it's exactly the same so that is not the problem.

Comparing the two articles I can see that there is a missing `SCRIPT` which is in charge of loading all your widgets on the sidebar. If you import the following script in the article, it works:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.getsitecontrol.com/46244/script.js"></script>`

Comment: It's not the problem. I added getsitecontrol widgets just few days ago, but the problem with sticky widget was long before.

Comment: @HDDmag Sorry, I misunderstood what were you referring to as a sticky since I was not seeing it from my computer. Emulating Smartphone, using a US IP address and clearing cookies was enough to be able to see it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Do you have adblocker? Or yes, maybe it shows ads to US based people..

Comment: @HDDmag I edited my answer. Is it useful for you now?